# where i define variable ( 15 to 20 variable) .. Appdelegate File, or .PCH File or define them extern

Tags: iphone, ios

i have 15 to 20 Variable i wants access it in my whole project. what is the best place for defining it and why?..  Appdelegate File,  .Pch file or define these Extern.

really thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing your app delegate from various points of your app creates a strong coupling between these components of your app.

Basically you are using globals through your app which is usually a good indication for an improvable application design.

Variables usually do not live in thin air. They exist in a context.  For example if you are using username and password you should get them from the system's keychain. The whole authentification process should be wrapped in an authentification class in which you would define the properties.

If you need to access information from various places of your app, you have to pass them as arguments of the initializer for example. This btw renders your individual components testable which is a good thing.

My advice is to rethink your app design first to not end in dependency hell later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can define them as properties in your `AppDelegate` class. For example:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *publicString;
```

If you want to make them `readonly` for external objects then you can define as follows:

1) in `AppDelegate.h`

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (retain, readonly, nonatomic) NSString *publicString;
```

2) in `AppDelegate.m`

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (retain, readwrite, nonatomic) NSString *publicString;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize publicString;
// other methods below
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one header file by name 'defines.h' and implement all defines and constants in it.
import this file in .Pch file

This is the best one, and will be separate from other classes.